# Wait for an image class to load in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, wait, onload

I want my code in JavaScript to pause when I create and image and wait for it to load before continuing. I tried writing this code:

```
var width, height = "width", "height"
img = new image()
image.onload = () => {width = this.width; height = this.height}
image.src = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/418893693106389024/aaed638ebdb3bfe2d4e1d3e7f9da62ef.png?size=256"
console.log(width, height)
```

However, when I run this code `width height` gets printed to the console. Is there a way to wait for the image to load before anymore code is run? If so, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTimeout() method and wait the seconds that you need before execute the lines after.

Comment: What if the image loads very slowly and takes more seconds than you think it will?

Comment: I would change the entire code, but he doesn't seems to be fetching those images, otherwise it will be easier to wait the response coming back and and execute the following lines after that.

Answer (score 0):

Put anything you need to use the width/height for in the `onload` so it only runs after the image has loaded:

```js
const image = new Image()
image.onload = function () {  
  console.log(this.width, this.height)
}
image.src = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/418893693106389024/aaed638ebdb3bfe2d4e1d3e7f9da62ef.png?size=256"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code had whole lot of miss matches.

by language convention classes are set with UpperCamel case so Image() not image()

secondly when we are encapsulating code in event listener such as on load we need everything that we need to execute in that encapsulation.

console.log out side of onload function is dealt at global level not sent in memory to execute latter on. So move it into on load function.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {let width = this.width; let height = this.height;
console.log(width, height);}
img.src = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/418893693106389024/aaed638ebdb3bfe2d4e1d3e7f9da62ef.png?size=256";
```